# Spring Batch - how to run steps in loop with values passed from a previous step/job

Tags: spring-batch

````
I want to achieve the use case where I have :
1. A task that calls an API to get some data and store to DB
2. Fetch all the records stored in DB from step#1 and call a second API with each of the IDs separately and store to DB
3. Fetch all the records stored in DB from step#2 and call a third API with each of the IDs separately and store to DB```

Something like -

1. GET ALL CONTINENTS AND SAVE in DB - 
2. FOR EACH CONTINENTs from DB GET ALL COUNTRIES and store in DB -
3. FOR EACH COUNTRY in DB GET ALL STATES in DB
````

Task A is simple - I can create a Job with a Step along with Reader/Processor/Writer.
Task B - I am confused how to fetch the DB records and then pass them to Step2's reader one by one.

Answer (score 0):

That requirement does not require running a step in a loop, it is not the same logic to repeat. Those are different steps operating on different data sets and doing different things. I see at least three ways to address this:

##### 1. create a single chunk-oriented step following the "driving query pattern"

In this [pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders), you would iterate over continent IDs using the item reader, and use an item processor to enrich items with countries and states, then write fully-loaded items to the database. This requires a single-step job.

##### 2. create a job with a sequence of three chunk-oriented steps where steps share data through the job execution context

There are different ways to share data between steps. The typical way to do that is through the job execution context. Each step can add data required by the next step in the job execution context, and the next step can get it from there. In your example, this would be something like:

- step 1: read continents and save them to the database, and store their IDs in the EC
- step 2: get continent IDs from the EC, fetch/save countries, and store countries IDs in the EC.
- step 3: gets countries IDs from the EC and fetch/save states

##### 3. Join data on the database side

A third way to address that requirement is to write a SQL query to join and grab the required data and save it to the database. This would require a single-step job.